# Spring boot: How to read external files reside in Tomcat when deployed as war

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I am deploying a Spring boot application as a war to my existing Tomcat server.
I will write to a json file which resides in `/conf/my.json` in the root of my Tomcat server.

My Spring boot will be deployed in `webapp` in the root of my Tomcat server so, say my Spring boot app called `mySpring`, it will be at location `/webapp/mySpring`.

How can I read the `my.json` in my Spring boot app?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to configure the path to my.json

Comment: how to configure the path? you mean hard code the path in Spring boot?

Comment: you could set a environment variable on the server like TOMCAT_HOME and use this

Answer (score 0):

you can use ResourceUtils to get the file.
File file= ResourceUtils.getFile(
                  "classpath:conf/my.json");